# Do auxiliary outputs important when training a siamese network?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

I have the next model structure:

```
class SiameseBinaryClassifier(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, embedding_size=256):
        super(SiameseBinaryClassifier, self).__init__()
        self.base_model = models.googlenet(weights=models.GoogLeNet_Weights.DEFAULT)
        self.base_model.aux_logits = False
        in_features = self.base_model.fc.in_features
        self.base_model.fc = nn.Linear(in_features, embedding_size)
        self.classifier = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(embedding_size * 2, 1),
            nn.Sigmoid()
        )

    def forward_once(self, x):
        return self.base_model(x)

    def forward(self, image1, image2):
        output1 = self.forward_once(image1)
        output2 = self.forward_once(image2)

        # Concatenate the embeddings of image1 and image2
        embeddings = torch.cat((output1, output2), dim=1)

        # Predict the similarity score using the classifier
        similarity_score = self.classifier(embeddings)
        
        # Squeeze the output tensor along the second dimension to remove the singleton dimension
        similarity_score = similarity_score.squeeze(dim=1)
        
        return similarity_score
```

I disabled aux logits. But if I understand correctly, auxiliary classifiers make training faster, because they create shortcuts for the gradients to flow backward. Maybe it's better to enable them? But I changed the original googlenet structure and made embeddings. If I just remove this line:
`self.base_model.aux_logits = False`, will my model train correctly? I will train this model for predicting if two anime faces are similar or not.